# passing functions

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers, arguments, fltk

Ok, it's been a while since I wrote in C++.
and I've never done anything quiet this high level.

So basically I need to create a class.
The constructor for the class needs to take a reference (or pointer) to a method form another class, or to a function.

Basically I have a class that needs to on occasion read a value from a fltk valuator (version 1.1.x), and then change some stuff about itself.
Each object will have it's own valuator associated with it. 
(they also have a link to another object of the same parent, which after updating them selves from the valuator will tell to update, and so on)

So how do i pass functions around, in constructors?

Comment: How do you know which object to call the passed method on? Is that object already known during construction, or later when you want to call it?

Comment: the passed method takes no parameters. It just returns a double value which is what the valuator is currently set to.
the Valuator object which has the method I want to pass has already been created.

Comment: Look into the standard functions mem_fun and mem_fun_ref. These may do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea if you posted some code. Then we could give more specific help.

Comment: 1. Seems unnatural procedural way for problem which should be resolved in OO way (class inheritance from common root, strategy pattern or few other) 2. code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example where a method of `Foo` is passed to the `Bar` constructor and later invoked on a given `Bar` object:

```
struct Foo
{
    int z;

    int add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y + z;
    }

    int mul(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y * z;
    }
};

typedef int (Foo::*foo_method)(int, int);

struct Bar
{
    foo_method m;

    Bar(foo_method m) : m(m) {}

    int call_on(Foo* foo)
    {
        return (foo->*m)(4, 2);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar bar(&Foo::add);

    Foo foo = { 123 };
    bar.call_on(&foo);
}
```

If, on the other hand, you already know the `Foo` object at `Bar` construction time, then `Bar` does not really care which class the method belongs to. All it needs is a functor to call later, and the `Foo` object can simply be bound by the client.

```
#include <functional>

struct Bar
{
    std::function<int (int, int)> f;

    Bar(std::function<int (int, int)> f) : f(f) {}

    int call()
    {
        return f(4, 2);
    }
};

using namespace std::placeholders;

int main()
{
    Foo foo = { 123 };
    Bar bar(std::bind(&Foo::add, &foo, _1, _2));

    bar.call();
}
```

If you don't have a C++0x compiler, replace `std::bind` with `std::tr1::bind` or `boost::bind`.

Comment: It is the latter case, unfortunatly I am stuck with GCC 3.42.
(dev c++), i don't want to update as this is the one my assessor will be using aswell.
I think I'll carry the whole object just to access it's methods.

Comment: @Oxi: So does `Bar` know at compile time which `Foo` method to call? In that case, you don't need function pointers at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor might look something like this:

```
// convenient typedef. This is for a pointer to a function in Foo
// The function returns void and takes no parameters.
typedef void (Foo::*FooPtr)();

class Bar {
public:
   Bar (FooPtr foo_ptr);
};
```

Check out some web references for more details on the syntax for pointer-to-members. It's a lot easier if you get familiar with it first.

As an additional note, check out the functions mem_fun and mem_fun_ref. These may do what you need.

Comment: Actually It might not be a member of a class.
It might be a function, i've created as little more than wrapper (say for converting degrees to radians).

Comment: @Oxi: "it might not" -> it actually is not? Or do you want to allow both?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to capture this is with `boost::function`. It can store function pointers, but also the result of binding a member function to an object.

For instance,

```
class Foo {
  Foo(boost::function<int(void)>);
};
```

will allow you to accept any source of integers.